# How can I get Wikipedia API results within alphabetical parameters?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm using the Wikipedia API to retrieve links within pages, and backlinks to those pages. Is there any way to filter results of `prop=links`, `prop=linkshere` or `list=backlinks` to retrieve only results that e.g. begin with a certain letter? Something like `from=La&to=Lz` would be nice - but it doesn't appear to be available.

At the moment the solution I have is to get ALL the links, using the continuation parameters, then just pull out those that match my criteria. But this can sometimes require numerous API calls, and seems a bit inelegant. Have I missed any other options?

Answer (score 1):

I've now had an answer from the [Wikimedia API mailing list](https://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/mediawiki-api/2015-February/003500.html): "There isn't anything like this available at the moment. It might be able to be added, but that doesn't help you right now."

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to results to be perfectly up-to-date, you can use the [database dumps](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20150304/) (published once a month or so) and then it's just a trivial SQL query.

Alternatively, you can implement that API yourself on [Wikimedia Labs](http://tools.wmflabs.org/) which allows you to create web services which have access to a live DB mirror of Wikipedia.